# "namespaces is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:default:cicd\" cannot list resource \"namespaces\"

Tags: kubernetes

I want to create a used for kubernetes. I tried this:

```
root@node1:~# kubectl create sa cicd
serviceaccount/cicd created
root@node1:~# kubectl get sa,secret
NAME                                SECRETS   AGE
serviceaccount/cicd                 0         5s
serviceaccount/default              0         23h
serviceaccount/my-service-account   0         20h

NAME          TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
secret/cicd   kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      20h
root@node1:~# cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: cicd
spec:
  serviceAccount: cicd
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: cicd
EOF
pod/cicd created
root@node1:~# kubectl exec cicd -- cat /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount                                                                  /token && echo
error: unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("cicd")
root@node1:~# kubectl exec cicd --cat /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token && echo
error: unknown flag: --cat
See 'kubectl exec --help' for usage.
root@node1:~# kubectl exec cicd -- cat /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token && echo
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ii1I........
root@node1:~# kubectl create token cicd
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI.......
root@node1:~# kubectl create token cicd --duration=999999h
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtp.........tOkAmd                                          DxF0vr11MhUozH3uBIHKykzPkHRRKw
root@node1:~# cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
metadata:
  name: cicd
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: "cicd"
EOF
secret/cicd configured
root@node1:~# kubectl get sa,secret
NAME                                SECRETS   AGE
serviceaccount/cicd                 0         67s
serviceaccount/default              0         23h
serviceaccount/my-service-account   0         20h
root@node1:~# kubectl describe secret cicd
Error from server (NotFound): secrets "cicd" not found
root@node1:~# kubectl describe secret cicd
Error from server (NotFound): secrets "cicd" not found
root@node1:~# kubectl describe sa cicd
Name:                cicd
Namespace:           default
Labels:              <none>
Annotations:         <none>
Image pull secrets:  <none>
Mountable secrets:   <none>
Tokens:              <none>
Events:              <none>
root@node1:~# kubectl get sa cicd -oyaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2023-03-14T12:39:07Z"
  name: cicd
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "130633"
  uid: 1fdc7419-26b0-41a5-af56-6e21171efd3b
root@node1:~# kubectl get sa,secret
NAME                                SECRETS   AGE
serviceaccount/cicd                 0         96s
serviceaccount/default              0         23h
serviceaccount/my-service-account   0         20h
root@node1:~# ^C
root@node1:~# curl -k  https://localhost:6443/api/v1/namespaces -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSU......"
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "namespaces is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:default:cicd\" cannot list resource                                           \"namespaces\" in API group \"\" at the cluster scope",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    "kind": "namespaces"
  },
  "code": 403
root@node1:~#
```

I use kubernetes v1.25.6. Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an associated clusterRole and clusterRoleBinding :

```bash
kubectl create clusterrole cicd --verb=get,list --resource=namespaces
kubectl create clusterrolebinding cicd --clusterrole=cicd --serviceaccount=default:cicd
```

If you've created your service account in another namespace that `default` make sure to update that last command accordingly

Comment: one thing is not clear: I used the default namespace so I need to put the second command like this: `kubectl create clusterrolebinding cicd --clusterrole=cicd --serviceaccount=cicd:default`

Comment: Absolutely. I didn't know your namespace that's why I've used a joker ;)

Comment: I made a mistake and now I get `error: failed to create clusterrolebinding: clusterrolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "cicd" already exists` is it possible to override or delete the old one?

Comment: Yes just run `kubectl delete clusterrolebinding cicd` and rerun the command. This is safe

Comment: Strange, I run the commands but I get again `"namespaces is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:default:cicd\" cannot list resource \"namespaces\" in API group \"\" at the cluster scope",
  "reason": "Forbidden",` Any idea why?

Comment: Yeah I've fixed my answer; you can delete the clusterRoleBinding and run the second command from my answser again

Comment: ok, that worked. Last question: at which line I have to add these bunding commands? Maybe before `kubectl get sa,secret`?

Comment: What are you trying to do ? I'm pretty sure that would be better to create yaml manifest for everything and apply them using `kubectl apply -f manifest.yaml` command

Comment: I want to create a service account to connect it with jenkins

Comment: In case you really want to create those from the command line you can put the clusterRole and clusterRoleBinding creation right after the `kubectl create sa cicd` command

Comment: But I really encourage you to put everything in a yaml file and call it with `kubectl apply -f <file>`